# Differentiability along different lines

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a function, is it always standard to determine its differentiability along the two lines $y=0$ and $y=x$ in order to check whether it is differentiable or not? Are there any other lines that can be used?

Comment: There are many other lines one can check! Differentiability requires that it be differentiable along any differentiable path leading to the point in question.

Comment: But we can't really check all lines, can we?

Comment: Not typically; there are other techniques for determining differentiability.

Comment: Like checking whether partial derivatives exist and are equal? And continuity?

Comment: That is one simple technique. The most general method is to look for the Jacobian matrix (using partial derivatives), and then verify that it satisfies the constraint shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions).

Comment: However, usually, I have seen the approach along a line... I have never come across the Jacobian in this context.

Comment: That's probably because no one expects you to be able to verify differentiability in this way, since it is harder to understand/apply.

Comment: Ah. But as a standard, will the method of directional derivatives or along lines work?

Comment: If you mean just straight lines, then no. The same link I gave you also gives an example of a function which has all directional derivatives (i.e., derivatives along straight lines), but is not differentiable, because it fails to have a derivative along a different type of curve.

Comment: you can consider even more complicated paths! Actually, *all* possible paths have to considered to prove differentiability (like in continuity)

Comment: A general trend that I have observed... functions with a maximum degree of 2 usually work when I use the test along $y=0$ and $y=x$. Degree 3 can be checked along a curve $y=x^2$.

Comment: @Artemisia: This [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597136/multivariable-calculus-two-path-test/597142#597142) may help your intuition.